# C# starts some cmd commands but other doesn't

Tags: c#, cmd, command

My windows forms app triggers an event:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
string strCmdText = "'/C ping server1.example.com > C:\\Users\\myusername\\Desktop\\1\\a.txt";
Process.Start("cmd.exe", strCmdText);
```

When executing, cmd.exe is getting spawned, runs for a while, the output is not displayed, but it is present in the redirected 1.txt file.

---

However, I need to run query command:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
string strCmdText = "'/C query user /server:server1.example.com > C:\\Users\\myusername\\Desktop\\1\\a.txt";
Process.Start("cmd.exe", strCmdText);
```

When executing, it spawns a cmd.exe but just for 1 second, then it dissapears, and the output is not present in the 1.txt file.

---

Is there any way to see what the query command does before it disappears, like keep it open when executing? Maybe is something interesting in there.
Or, am I doing something wrong? Maybe I need to run the command otherwise?

Comment: Instead executing `cmd` to execute `query` you could execute `query` directly.

Comment: How about putting your command into a batch file and adding a pause at the end of the file?  Then execute the batch file from C#

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
string outputProcess = "";
string errorProcess = "";

using (Process process = new Process())
{
    process.StartInfo.FileName = yourPath;
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = yourArguments;
    process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.Start();
    outputProcess = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    errorProcess = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: I edited process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"; and process.StartInfo.Arguments = "query user /server:ctx020-75it.group.pirelli.com"; This spawns cmd.exe but it doesn't shot anything in the output, nor the 1.txt gets filled.

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to run the code as yours. just replace the "CMD" to "CMD /k"

Comment: I replaced the code with /k, and now it opens the cmd.exe, it remains there, but it doesn't find the query.exe app. And the strange thing is, from that spawned CMD, i changed directory manually into the C:/windows/system32/ and the query.exe is not there. But if I open the cmd from my computer, query.exe is present...this is really odd.. If I take a look into the task managers, the spawned CMD is named "Windows Command Processor (32 bit)", and if I open cmd manually, in the taskbar is named "Windows Command Processor"

Comment: Process.Start(@"C:/windows/system32/cmd.exe", strCmdText)

Comment: same thing bro. nothing changes.